# How to set userName in front of UserId (at top parent key)

Tags: javascript, firebase

OK, In Firebase database structure, we have **key** and its **value**.

On user's registration I am storing three main things, First **Email**, Second **Username**, and third **Phone Number**. For now I am storing these three things under unique **userId** generated by Firebase automatically.

The code I am using for this, is given below-

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref().child(uid).set({

    email: user.email,
    userName: user_Name,
    phoneNumber: phone_Number_Of_TheUser
  });
```

I want to set the **UserName** in front of **userId**.

**IN FRONT OF USER ID** mean, if I am storing UserId as the top parent key, then I want to set the **userName** as its value

[image: This Image Describes the model of data structure I want to use in Firebase]

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic key"? IMHO You should better explain better what you really want to do, as it is not 100% clear.

Comment: OK I understand. So Dynamic here refers to the key in Firebase real-time-database, where I can set its name as User's uid. 

uid here means-
 firebase.auth().currentUser.uid.  
So that's why I called it dynamic key. 
 Actually I want to know, how to set Its value. Value here means The value we put in front of key in Firebase real-time-database.

Answer (score 0):

Umm if you want just the email or name with the uid, you should try something with backtick, which lets you create template literals are enclosed by the back-tick () character instead of double or single quotes, like

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref().child(`${user.email}-${uid}`).set({

    email: user.email,
    userId: user_Id_of_the_user,
    phoneNumber: phone_Number_Of_TheUser
  });
```

or

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref().child(`${user.name}-${uid}`).set({

    email: user.email,
    userId: user_Id_of_the_user,
    phoneNumber: phone_Number_Of_TheUser
  });
```

Comment: I am still getting two problem in using email as it can not set a path with character such as @ in URL. And the second method you told me, there I am unable to use USESR ID

Comment: Umm if you dont have a `user.name` then use `ref().child(`${user_Id_of_the_user}-${uid}`).set({` Did you try that?
Also, yes @ cant be added so in that case you can just add the emails first part with the domain part.
you can do that by ```.child(`${user .email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"))}-${uid}`).set({```

Comment: Hey friend, Actually you didn't get my meaning of my question of adding user name as value at key(uid). Can you see the part in my code where I am writing     phoneNumber: phone_Number_Of_TheUser.     Here phoneNumber is a Key, where I am calling it dynamic key(for the uid) and its value (phone_Number_Of_TheUser), where I want to set UserId. It is the example given by me, which may help you to understand where I want to set the UserId. I hope it will help you to understand my problem

Comment: hey, @subhendu, friend, please help me out from this problem.. I will be thankful for you

Comment: Honestly, I am confused what you want. Are you trying to set a auto generated id or string to set for your userId? Or you are trying to add the whole object under the uid as a key? for example, uid: {email: ' ', userId:' ', phoneNumber: ' '} this uid you want it to be unique?  Or the value of the userId you want it to be unique or autogenerated?  I am such dumb. You can try to explain it again. Sorry

Comment: You are not dumb friend, I am , I had not used technical word correctly, but now I have rectified my mistakes and edited the question completely. May be it will help you now. Pardon for my mistakes... You are truly co-operative.

Comment: `firebase.database().ref().child(user_Name).set({

    email: user.email,
    userName: user_Name,
    phoneNumber: phone_Number_Of_TheUser
  });` that's all you need to do.